# What is an example of two Banach spaces $X,Y$ such that $X$ embeds isometrically but not linearly into $Y$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, isometry

By a result of Godefroy and Kalton if $X,Y$ are separable Banach spaces and $X$ embeds isometrically into $Y$, then $X$ embeds with a linear isometry into $Y$.

Is this result known to fail for nonseparable spaces? That is, is there a known example of two (necessarily nonseparable) Banach spaces $X,Y$ such that $X$ embeds isometrically into $Y$, but such that there is no linear isometric embedding of $X$ into $Y$?

This question was crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410123/what-is-an-example-of-two-banach-spaces-x-y-such-that-x-embeds-isometrically) and answered there.

Comment: Why do you think such an example exists? Or might even be “simple”? Within $C_p$ theory this is a well studied problem ( but that “ merely” gives a TVS (locally convex) as examples.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma that's a good point, I am expecting this result to fail for nonseparable spaces, but I don't know for sure that it does. I'm updating the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered by Nik Weaver on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410123/what-is-an-example-of-two-banach-spaces-x-y-such-that-x-embeds-isometrically) in the positive: indeed this result is known to be false for nonseparable spaces.

Comment: This is (almost) how it should be done.  If not answered here after 5 months, then ask in MO.  Actually, one week should be enough delay.